# Stunnel keeps hanging and then needs to be restarted

Tags: linux, stunnel

I am running Stunnel on Ubuntu 22.04.
Every now and then it will start hanging(but the service shows as active if I check the status) and I then if I restart the service it will start working again.

It seems to be setup on Ubuntu without a systemd unit file.

Is there some way to keep it working without manually restarting it and without having to create a systemd unit file?

Answer (score 0):

So far as a temporary fix I just have a cron that runs every 5mins to do:

```
service stunnel4 restart
```